# How to get the List item Id in javascript while in the display form

Tags: 2013, javascript, list-item, display-form

Is there is a way to retrieve the List Item Id (ID) that you are currently viewing (`Display.aspx` from) in javascript.

I have searched through ctx and the `_spPageContextInfo` but have not found any solutions. Most the mentions online speak of getting the selected item in the `AllItems.aspx` view but I am interested in getting it in the Display Form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with javascript and JSRequest.

The ID should be passed in via the URL, (ie. 'DispForme.aspx?Id=11'), then use the below code to retrieve the '11'..

```
JSRequest.EnsureSetup(); 
var itemId = JSRequest.QueryString["ID"];
```

Comment: I believe he is asking about List Id and not Item Id.

Comment: I made a typo, you were correct in your assumption Simon.

Answer (score 1):

ItemID, just use the URL:

```
var itemIdINT = GetUrlKeyValue("ID", false, location.href);
```

ListId in the SP forms there are a couple of fields where you can extract the List GUID via jquery... e.g.:

```
var listIdGUID = $('[id^=_ListSchemaVersion_]').attr('id').toString().match(new RegExp(/\{(.*?)\}/))[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use something like this:

```
function getQS(key) {
  var regex=new RegExp('[\\?&amp;]'+key+'=([^&amp;#]*)');
  var qs=regex.exec(window.location.href);
  return qs[1];
}

var itemID = getQS('ID');
```